# how to do zooming image xcode??

Tags: iphone, xcode, zooming

i have a problem. I have this code a zoom doesn't work.

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zoomimage.jpeg"];

CGRect yFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 432);

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
[imageView setImage:image];

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:yFrame];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height)];
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.4;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
[scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

}

Comment: It's time to study apple's sample source codes buddy

Answer (score 5):

First, set the delegate of scrollview to your self.

```
scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Now, Add this delegate method of `UIScrollView` in your class to enable zooming on the image.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**.h Controller:**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView; 
UIImageView *imageView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

**.m Controller:**

```
@synthesize scrollView, imageView;


-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollVi­ew *)scrollView{ 

return imageView;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName.png"]]; 
self.imageView = tempImageView; 
[tempImageView release]; 
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0; 
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.6; 
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; 
scrollView.delegate = self; 
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

This code worked for me :)

Comment: Since you should be using ARC (since Xcode 4, more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting), this should work if you remove this line >>> [tempImageView release]; <<< from the .m Controller. Let ARC figure out the memory retaining/releasing!